# Livewire AppServiceProvider boot method didn't execute on update

Tags: laravel-livewire

In Laravel AppServiceProvider file the boot method apply for the first time only, on Livewire update for example for validation or anything language returns to default.

```
public function boot()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('ar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ar');
```

or it might be convenient for you something like this?

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

Comment: Carbon::setLocale('ar') | Work fine but when livewire component get updated the boot method didn't fire again of course because it's PHP not dynamic, I need in this point livewire save Carbon local attribute